# Can't filter Firebase model with REST API

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to use Firebase's REST API to only retrieve episodes with a specific Podcast API. The curl request is returning all the episodes in the database, not just the ones where podcastID="863897795"

Here's the first query I tried:

```
curl https://myurl.firebaseio.com/episodes.json?orderBy=\"podcastID\"&equalTo="863897795"
```

and here's the second:

```
curl https://myurl.firebaseio.com/episodes.json?orderBy=\"podcastID\"&endAt="863897795"&startAt="863897795"
```

Here's my model:

```
episodes
 b44dfeb16d5feb75d592d2f21b605cbb
 downloadURLString: "http://traffic.libsyn.com/timferriss/Tim_Ferris..."
 duration: 0
 fileType: 
"audio/mpeg"
 podcastID: 
"863897795"
 publishDate: 
1456271851
 summary: 
"This episode is a special double header. It fea..."
 title: 
"Kaskade and Sekou Andrews: The Musician and the..."
 f68ee7bd673662a5b416577536ea8e6d
 downloadURLString: 
"http://starbucks.podspot.de/files/starbucks_cof..."
 duration: 
0
 fileType: 
"audio/mpeg"
 podcastID: 
"218302289"
 publishDate: 
1226305317
 summary: 
"Das \"Coffee and Crime\" Krimi-Festival in Kooper..."
 title: 
"Starbucks Special - Coffee and Crime Festival R..."
```

Here's my indexing:

```
 "episodes": {
      ".indexOn": ["podcastID"]
    }
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Aside from my previous comment, I'm guessing the problem is caused by the way you're escaping the quotes. Try `curl 'https://myurl.firebaseio.com/episodes.json?orderBy="podcastID"&equalTo="863897795"&print=pretty'`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the improperly escaped quotes were the problem. thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. Please do remember the bit about pictures of JSON for the next time, as I now had no easy way to validate that was indeed your mistake. I'm going to vote to close as a typo, as people having the same problem are not likely to find this question (because they're not aware that the quotes might be the mistake).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen swapped out image with real json